# Как совершить асинхронную операцию в условии if?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx-coroutines, koin

Когда пробую такой способ

```
if (runBlocking { get<ApiService>().getProductAll().isSuccessful })
```

то вылезает эта ошибка

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again
```

полный код условия

```
if (get<ApiService>().getProductAll().isSuccessful) {
    request.newBuilder().apply {
        header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + 365)
    }.build()
    Log.d("GetStateCache", "Данные из кеша не используются")
} else {
    request.newBuilder().apply {
        header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7)
    }.build()
    Log.d("GetStateCache", "Данные из кеша используются")
}
```

Comment: Блокирующий вызов по определению не асинхронный, а асинхронный по определению не может возвращать результат немедленно, поэтому использовать его в условии не представляется возможным. Давайте лучше начнём с того, чего вы хотите добиться таким способом - наверняка это можно сделать иначе.

Comment: нужно получать в условие получать тип Boolean, но метод suspend. Поэтому вылезает такое

```
Suspend function 'getProductAll' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function
```

Comment: Так и выполняйте условие в корутине, а не корутину в условии. Я ещё раз спрашиваю: чего вы пытаетесь добиться этим кодом - для чего вам само условие? Дайте больше контекста задачи.

Comment: if нужен чтобы определять нужно ли использовать данные из кеша или нет. Если условие равно true то данные используются из запроса, если false то из кеша. А если обернуть if в корутино то приложение сильно лагает, а через время вылетает. Я щас скину полный код

Comment: Очень похоже что вы пытаетесь исправить последствия неправильного решения другой проблемы, вместо того чтобы исправить само решение. Жуткие лаги и переполнение стека/памяти намекают на непреднамеренную рекурсию. Попробуйте начать сначала и задать вопрос по той проблеме. То есть как организовать запрос так, чтобы в случае неуспеха данные брались из кеша (или что вы там пытаетесь добиться).

Comment: в конструкции if это реализовано уже. А ```get<ApiService>().getProductAll().isSuccessful``` возвращает true если запрос успешен, и false если не успешен

Comment: Ну если не работает оно как надо - наверное неправильно реализовано. Нет?

Comment: Сама конструкцию работает как надо, проблема в ```Suspend function 'getProductAll' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function```